# Is this a recognised and/or safe PHP idiom?

Tags: php

I found this function in some code being advocated as 'good' on another SE site.

```
public static function init()
        {
            is_null( self::$instance ) AND self::$instance = new self;
            return self::$instance;
        }
```

Can someone explain this line in english for me?

```
is_null( self::$instance ) AND self::$instance = new self;
```

I am not interested in hearing why you think `singletons` are bad. I'm aware this code is designed to return an instance of the containing class but I just don't understand how to read that one line. What is the result of `self::$instance = new self;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly clean code. 
The line first tests if the singleton already exists, if so it is returned. If not, then a new instance is created, stored inside the singletons class static instance attribute and returned.

One might stumble about the unconventional notation using the `AND` operator. But that is perfectly valid PHP code: The part behind the `AND` is only executed if the condition before is true So if not object exists in this case.

The result (return value) of the assignment of the construct `self::$instance = new self` is irrelevant here. It has fulfilled its duty, the object is created. I personally would prefer this construct to be written inside backets. But in general the assignment operator also has a return value when evaluated in this way. This is why you can also make very clean code using this construction: `if (FALSE===($result=action())) {do_something();}`.

Comment: I think that's where I stumble. I expect AND to mean 'in addition to'. My brain expects the whole line to be a condition even though the second half is an assignment. What does AND really mean here?

Comment: @codecowboy, `AND` here just ensures that we only assign `new self` if `self::$instance` is null.

Comment: Your intuition is right: it IS some form of conditional. That is why it is working. Imagine that line being the conditional inside an if statement: an AND-operator is evaluated by first evaluating the part left from it. Only if that is true (fulfills the conditional) then the right hand part is evaluated. That is what is desired here: you do _not_ want a new object getting created if the singleton already exists. So I would call this a clever usage of a conditional operator. More frequent one sees the `OR` operator to be used like this: `do_something() OR exit('failed!');`

Comment: I find it terse and unreadable. Time to change careers I think. But thanks!

Comment: There are indeed different styles programmers use. Some find this more readable, others prefer different notations. It is a good thing that there is a variety, I'd say. I oppose those people how claim that there is only one way to do things right. :-) To _me_ this snippet looks very clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

It basically means that if `self:$instance` is `null`, make `self:$instance` `new self`.

A more verbose method would be:

```
if(is_null(self::$instance)){
    self::$instance = new self;
}
```

To answer your actual question, the result of `self::$instance = new self;` would be `true`, but that's irrelevant because we're just using it to assign the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `self::$instance = new self;` is that the static `$instance` variable gets initialized by the current object (as it didn't exist beforehand).